# Test password on ecryptfs

Tags: ecryptfs

We need to reboot a server that has a ecryptfs mount point on it, the problem is that we lost the password, and found one that might be it. We want to try it before we reboot so we have a chance to migrate the data in case it's wrong.

Comment: What about using `ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase` to change the password? It'll ask for the old password and error out if it's not correct.

Comment: Similar to @ceejayoz 's idea,  using `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase` would be an excellent idea too, and would give you a chance to backup the actual mount passphrase (that's if you're using a "standard" eCryptFS setup that stores the mount passphrase in a `wrapped-passphrase` file that's unlocked using the user's login passphrase)